# Replace lamp in old amplifier

Tags: amplifier, lamp, dual, replacement

I am trying to replace a fried lamp in my very old amplifier (a Dual CV 1280 Integrated). As I essentially only use the mode that is indicated by the fried lamp, I thought I could just switch it with a working one. However I have no idea how to get it out. Can anyone enlighten me? I don't even know how they are called, hence no idea what to google. It only says `Osram 24/1.2`.

Photos from front and back (the grey thingies):

[image: amp lamp]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just rotate the plastic from the back (CCW to "unscrew", it's sort of a bayonet base-like action). I have the same general kind of lamp in the instrument cluster of an E28 chassis automobile. The metal contacts work against pads on the single-sided PCB. It's a [24V 1.2W bulb](http://www.lampengrossier.nl/24V-12W-GRIJS/GREY-B85D-DASBOARDLMP-1/pt) (photo from linked site).

[image]

---

As @Jack mentions *some* such bulbs have removable bulbs and you can replace the bulb without removing the base from the PCB (but some are soldered in). Here is a (similar, but not exact) 12V example showing both:

[image]

It's pretty easy to break the bulb trying to get it out, in my experience, so I buy the ones with base attached for slightly more money.

Answer (score 0):

They are called glass Wedge indicators..
They pull directly out of the base.

They come in various sizes from T3.25 through to T20

[image]

Your particular indicator is probably not more than 1-1.2 W and most of the auto indicators are 3-5 W or higher .....so don't use them.

If you want to move an existing working bulb to this position simply pull the bulb directly up from the PCB and push the new one into the base. You might have to ease the little metal shoulders that you see at the sides of the bulb. DO NOT twist or you will break the glass base.